# Intermittent signature expired error while testing lambda function using JMeter

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter

I am load testing an application with 10 million concurrent users and could see intermittent 403 - forbidden error with below message:

```
{"message":"Signature expired: 20221104T181501Z is now earlier than 20221104T182505Z (20221104T183005Z - 5 min.)"}
```

Apllication is deployed on AWS wherein endpoints hits to lambda functions underneath API gateway which further intracts with S3. And this error comes only under heavy user load with some defined RPS, otherwise it works fine.

Since I am running the load from Blazemeter and setting some RPS limit to ~1500, suspecting Blazemeter is trying to put the delay between preprocessor where the code is written to generate sig4 signature and http request sampler. And sometimes these delay is more than 5 mins because of that x-amz-date used in header is five mins older than the actual time - when http request actually got invoked and causes these exceptions intermittently.

Wondering if we have any mechanism to invoke wait time first (as I need to set RPS limit from Blazemeter) followed by code written in preprocessor and finally http request of JMeter, this will make sure there is no much difference between generated time in code vs when http request got trigged. Please suggest on this or any other workaround which can help to overcome this issue.

[code used to generate AWS signature in preprocessor](https://github.com/jinlo02/Jmeter_AWS_Signature/blob/master/PRE_PROCESSOR.groovy)

Answer (score 0):

I can only suggest checking [Engine Health](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000290058-Engine-Health-Report) for your JMeter load generators as it might be the case they're overloaded can don't have sufficient amount of resources for generating a proper signature as cryptographic functions are very CPU intensive.

If this is the case adding [more JMeter Slaves](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html) should solve your problem.

Also if you're artificially limiting JMeter's samplers execution rate be informed that [Timers are executed after Pre-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) so you could move your signature generating logic into the timer itself, this way you will always have "fresh" signature.

Comment: delay is being introduced by throughput shaping timer, not using any explicit timer.